# Write webm blobs / base64 to file via node mediaRecorder

Tags: node.js, stream, mediarecorder, webm

I'm trying to record a webcam stream via my node server into a new file. To get the webm Blobs I use the `mediaRecorder` api and then send those via `binaryJs` to my node server. Then I don't know how to proceed. My current code in node looks like this, but I don't know how to write the chunks to a file:

```
var binaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var serverBinaryVideo = binaryServer({port: 9002});

serverBinaryVideo.on('connection', function(client) {

    client.on('stream', function(stream, meta) {

        stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        });

        stream.on('end', function() {

        });


    });
});
```

Does it work like this, or should I convert the blob to base64 on my client?

Client Js looks like this for now:

```
var clientVideo = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9002/');

clientVideo.on('open', function() {
  // for the sake of this example let's put the stream in the window
  window.StreamVideo = clientVideo.createStream();
});


var options = {
    audioBitsPerSecond : 128000,
    videoBitsPerSecond : 2500000,
    mimeType : 'video/webm;codecs=h264' //mp4 not supported in chrome. Original: 'video/webm'
}

var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audiovideostream, options);
mediaRecorder.start(500); //call every 500ms

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    // console.log("mediarecorderData");
    // console.log(e);
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.data); 
    videoProcess(e.data)
    // chunks.push(e.data);
}

mediaRecorder.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
    // chunks.push(e.data);
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Hi, I managed to do this somehow but in the end didn't need the webcam stream anymore. I'll take a look into my git to see.

Comment: vinni - do you remember how you wrote the blob to a .webm file?  I figured out how to base64 encode it, that wasn't hard, and I could pass that up to the server if I needed it.  But I'm trying to figure out how to write it to a properly formatted .webm file, and I have not found out yet how to do that.  I would prefer a C# .net solution, but javascript could help too.  Thanks in advance for anything you remember and can tell me.

Comment: Footniko - did you ever find a solution to write the .webm file?